# SQL Server Create Date From TSQL

Tags: t-sql, installation, server

Basically, I am looking for a way to pull the date that the SQL instance was created, using *TSQL*, ie a *CreateDate* for the server itself. I could find nothing in the docs or the site.
I know I can go scrolling through the system to find a date in the file system, but thought that their might be a way to do it as easily as I can for *sys.objects*. I thought that maybe I could use a *CreateDate* off of a table in master or msdb, but that seems to be the date that MS created those. I am running 2019.

Any suggestion would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Query `syslogins`.`createdate` for `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several options you can use

```
/*********** Retrieve SQL Server Installation Date Time ************/

SELECT 
@@SERVERNAME AS Server_Name, 
create_date AS SQL_Server_Install_Date
FROM sys.server_principals WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE name = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' OR name = N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE';
GO

SELECT
@@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name],  
createdate AS SQL_Server_Install_Date
FROM    sys.syslogins 
WHERE name = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' OR name = N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE';
GO

SELECT create_date
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE sid = 0x010100000000000512000000
GO

-->> Check the setup\installation logs

SELECT createdate
FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE name='sa'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronen.  The last one actually comes back with a VERY old date, but the other 3 work well.

Comment: You are most welcome `:-)` . Each solution has some limitations and the only one you can really count on is "`Check the setup\installation logs`". The rest of the options based on your service configuration and previous installations. Note: don't forget to close the thread once you a solution which fit your needs